# how to fetch swatch images from another folder ( not from swatches folder )

Tags: magento-1.9, color-swatches, configurable-swatches

I have created new attribute color_group. I have added multiple colors to color_group attribute. Now I want to add the color images to that colors.
How can I assign color images to that colors.

Answer (score 0):

If your color name is red then magento finds `red.png` in `media/wysiwyg/swatches`

So just named as other attribute and your work is done

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable-swatch.html

**EDIT**

If you want to change folder for your attribute you can debug this file

`app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php`

Comment: This answer is correct if i used color attribute. I want to use color_group attribute. Also I  am using color attribute at the same time. So Whenever I upload the swatch images, it goes to swatches folder.

I want to upload that swatch images in another folder for color_group attribute.

Comment: @gt06 if this answer help you to solve your problem, then there is option to mark as accepted so other users face the same problem or have the same question take benefits from this post

Comment: My question is different. Your answer is not proper to my question. If i added color_group swatches, the for that color_group swatch attribute, in which folder should i upload the swatch image.???